# How to avoid overwriting of cell style format in xlsxwriter (Python)?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am on Python `2.7`, xlsxwriter `0.8.4`.

I have a list of values, `int`s and `float`s and I want to be able to apply different number format when writing the data into the sheet's cell.

However, when using the `set_num_format` method, the lastly applied format will be applied to already written cells. **I wonder whether it's possible to apply a cell formatting for every write operation individually? If not, how else one could manage multiple format objects without hard coding** them as in:

`simple_style_percent_int = workbook.add_format({'bold': False, 'font_color': 'black','font_size': 11, 'font_name': 'Calibri','text_wrap': True, 'num_format': '0"%"'})`


`simple_style_percent_decimal = workbook.add_format({'bold': False, 'font_color': 'black','font_size': 11, 'font_name': 'Calibri','text_wrap': True, 'num_format': '0.0"%"'})`

The code I run:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

percent_format = workbook.add_format()

for item in [22.0, 34.68]:

    if item.is_integer():
        percent_format.set_num_format('0"%"')
        worksheet.write(1,1, int(item), percent_format)
    else:
        percent_format.set_num_format('0.00"%"')
        worksheet.write(2,1, item, percent_format)

workbook.close()
```

The script will apply the lastly used (i.e. decimal percent) format to all cells that had this format during previous write operations (however, I want `22` to be represented as `22%`, not as `22.00%`.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you having multiple formats defined as follows:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

percent_format_1 = workbook.add_format()
percent_format_1.set_num_format('0"%"')

percent_format_2 = workbook.add_format()
percent_format_2.set_num_format('0.00"%"')

for item in [22.0, 34.68]:
    if item.is_integer():
        worksheet.write(1,1, int(item), percent_format_1)
    else:
        worksheet.write(2,1, item, percent_format_2)

workbook.close()
```

This would give you:

[image: excel screenshot]

Note, changing a format will cause the change to be applied to cells that have already been written using that format. Namely the final format is used to display all associated cells, which is why you saw it change. See [Modifying formats](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#modifying-formats) for more information.

---

To apply this to a whole column of data using these two different formats, you could enumerate the data as follows:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

percent_format_1 = workbook.add_format()
percent_format_1.set_num_format('0"%"')

percent_format_2 = workbook.add_format()
percent_format_2.set_num_format('0.00"%"')

for rowy, item in enumerate([22.0, 34.68, 1.0, 5.0, 6.8], start=1):
    if item.is_integer():
        worksheet.write(rowy, 1, int(item), percent_format_1)
    else:
        worksheet.write(rowy, 1, item, percent_format_2)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. This could work for me. How would you handle though the case that I've mentioned in the question about having multiple formats (without hardcoding everything)? I guess having `percent_format_1` and `percent_format_2` formats would imply that each of those should have own definition of parameters. Any productivity tips on that? Was hoping for some kind of super class that has those boilerplate params such as font size, font type, etc.

Comment: I don't think that approach is possible with xlsxwriter. You can apply a single format to a whole row or column, but you need to apply it manually on a per cell basis.

Comment: thanks a ton. Pity I am not aware of a way to have a standard style that can be applied to multiple styles on the fly without actually creating a new style.